# PHP / Apache - Refreshing screen while exec'd script is running

Tags: php, apache, webserver, exec

One page on my web site is a PHP script that uses exec() to launch a separate PHP script which generates a PDF document.

The PDF may take 30 seconds to generate.  When I hit the refresh button during this process, I am finding inconsistent behavior.  On both my Mac and Windows local dev machines, refreshing the page will hang Apache.  On my production Linux server, I don't seem to experience the problem.

Why is this?  I don't care that my dev machines hang, I just want to be sure that it won't ever happen in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you run `exec()` every time the page is rendered, or do you have some logic to check whether the previous php script has finished?

You may be generating a new PDF every time you refresh the page.
If this takes a while, it might be hanging Apache because all the threads in its thread-pool are waiting for the exec'ed scripts to finish, if they're not detached properly.

If that is the case, it could certainly hang Apache on your production server.